# Making midis off of real songs - syncing tempo

Tags: midi

Occasionally throughout a song, the tempo will change by 2-3 BPM, completely throwing off the song. As a result, I have to put the tempo change in the midi itself to sync, but even then it's slightly off. This makes it difficult to gauge whether something is out of sync or if my midi is wrong. Is there a way painless way of making a midi sync with the music it's based on?

Answer (score 3):

There is a way to tempo shift in several DAW's.  They allow you to either tap tempo, or move bar and beat lines to match up to the audio track.  Digital Performer, Reason, and Logic have this capability.  Cubase probably has it too, although I haven't personally tested it.  Once you've matched the tempo you can export a MIDI tempo map.